# How to use Google Cloud Speech to Text i can`t find any info anywhere?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I need help in using google cloud. Speech to text function more precise. I`ve looked on youtube and found only old tutorials that look nothing like the interface is today. My question is what do I do where do I write and what do I write in order for google cloud to take my text to analyze it and spit it out as text.
Thanks a lot please help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to follow the quickstart over at the [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries), this is the quickest and easiest way to try it in my opinion.

Additionally, it has a button in case you get stuck so you can provide feedback to either the tutorial or GCP itself.

Hope you find this useful.